# Erlang Supervisors - Shared Process Mailboxes

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a supervisor process that monitors two child processes; a primary process and a backup process (in case the primary process exits).

If the primary process goes down whilst there are still messages in its mailbox, is there a way for the backup process to take over and process the messages that were left in the original primary process mailbox?

Comment: Nodes or processes? Those are two different concepts in the Erlang world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean processes instead of nodes, and you want to make sure all incoming messages are processed. Either by the primary process or by the backup process, it's best to store incoming messages directly in a Mnesia table. That way you can continue processing in the backup proces.

That said, I think the problem you are trying to solve can be handled automatically by OTP. You never need to create backup processes. You can just tell the supervisor to re-spawn the same gen_server if one crashed.

Comment: [Question from an interested reader].  Does this mean the mailbox for a process survives a respawn?  i.e. any messages in the mailbox prior to termination will still be there when the process is respawned?  thx.

Comment: No, it is lost, that's why you need to put it in an ets or Mnesia table.

Comment: ah - ok.  Didn't think they survived, just read your answer wrong.  Thx for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do in such a situation is push incoming messages into an ets table. There are some subtleties to this. Discussed further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172381/data-persistence-when-worker-process-dies-how/4181192#4181192)